# Host Client-Side web part from SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm following the SPFx Getting started guide for web parts and I'm at [part 4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/hosting-webpart-from-office-365-cdn).

In the note at the top of the page, there is mention of hosting from a SharePoint Library from your tenant (immediately after the "Azure CDN" link), but there is no reference of how to do this. Are there any guides out there that I could follow to try this method?

Comment: For more details about **Hosting your SPFx Client Side Webpart on Office 365 public CDN** go to the following link : https://blog.mastykarz.nl/publish-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-office-365-public-cdn/

Comment: I guess there's not a way to do this without needing to be an admin and enable the CDN settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While CDNs are good for performance, you dont need to necessarily enable them just to use `SPFx` webparts.

Just modify the `Config > write-manifests.json` and add your SharePoint location as below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://dev.office.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/write-manifests.schema.json",
  "cdnBasePath": "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/test/SiteAssets/"
}
```

Upload your artefacts in the Site Assets or any other document library.

After that, run the `gulp bundle --ship` and `gulp package-solution --ship` and follow the instructions mentioned in the link that you shared and upload the app in app catalog.

Using this `cdnBasePath` you can consume files directly from SharePoint library itself instead of enabling Office 365 CDN or using Azure or another CDN provider.

Comment: When you say artefacts, do you mean the temp/deploy/ files?

Comment: (Along with my previous question) I am able to add the app to my site contents, but after if finishes installing am not able to add it to a page. Is this because I didn't upload the correct things to the SiteAssets library? Or is this caused by something else?

Comment: 1)Yes, temp deploy files. It's the same procedure as mentioned. 2) could be something else. Is it deployed correctly?

Comment: Try and deploy a simple hello world spfx webpart to test this out. Will help isolate the problem

Comment: Deploying a hello-world part worked properly. The one thing i noticed was that the deploy file had 3 files in it instead of the 2 that my original part had. I tried gulp clean and rebuilding, but it still only created 2 files.

Comment: hmm, not really sure why this is happening. But certainly looks like issue in the webpart/build process .

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on. I created a new instance and copied what i needed from the old files into new files, it still compiled into 2 files in the deploy folder, but this time it shows up as a webpart? My best guess is that at somepoint I was trying something and touched the wrong setting. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to create and configure a azure storage account but need to link it into azure.

so first do this section to setup azure cdn link to create the storage account

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn

then follow on with this to setup the link in azure and the spfx webpart to link to the cdn instead

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/deploy-web-part-to-cdn